# SQLite Boolean WHERE to check for 0 and NULL value

Tags: sqlite, casting, boolean

I'm looking for a SQLite WHERE clause which will give me the records if they are:

```
0 (false)
NULL (false)
1 (true)
```

So besides 0 and 1 i also have records with NULL.

I now do a

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (MyBoolean IS NULL OR MyBoolean = 0) AND SomeOtherValue NOT NULL;
```

When using

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE NOT MyBoolean AND SomeOtherValue NOT NULL;
```

The value=NULL records are not found, only the value=0 records :o(

Do i have to cast my column as a boolean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Casting won't help here (`CAST (null AS sometype)` is still NULL). Anything that you can use will be more or less equivalent of the expression you use now: I find `WHERE NOT COALESCE(MyBoolean,0)` a bit more readable, but that's a personal preference.

Comment: thanks Anton. I think i am best of trying to prevent the NULL value.

Comment: SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MyBoolean != 1;
This only gives me the 0-value records. How can i get the NULL records too?

Comment: `NULL != anything` is always `NULL`, so go for `COALESCE`. (I can say in advance that `NOT (MyBoolean=1)` also doesn't help, because `NULL=anything` is `NULL` and `NOT(NULL)` is `NULL`).

Comment: thanks. So NULL values are not that helpfull as i hoped they would be.

Comment: NULL is the father of despair. Especially with booleans. How about making it NOT NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Handling NULL booleans is really tricky indeed.

I don't know anything about the architecture of your code, but try to consider the following:

Make your `MyBoolean` `NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE` (or `FALSE`, depends).

It might require minor code refactoring, but it will keep all the `SELECT`s clean, readable, and will escape you from using hacky methods.

I will repeat myself: this solution might not work if somehow your architecture is very inflexible and you cannot do this sort of refactors.

Hope this helps anybody.

Answer (score 0):

[json_quote](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html#jvalid) translate `null` and `false` to 0, and `true` to 1. just use it : `json_quote(X)='1'`